# What's the difference between "disallow", "reject", and "silence" when blocking calls?

Tags: android, telephony, callscreeningservice

I'm trying to block incoming calls on Android. For that I'm using the [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telecom/CallScreeningService) approach, where my code has to call `respondToCall` in response to receiving a call. In the [response builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telecom/CallScreeningService.CallResponse.Builder) there are 3 boolean options that confuse me: `disallowCall`, `rejectCall`, and `silenceCall`. What's the difference between them? Also, can multiple of them be set at the same time?